# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32Registry' from .NET Standard Library Consumed by .NET Framework Console App

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

## The Problem

The [Microsoft.Win32.Registry nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/) is giving me a lot of issues . We had .NET Framework 4.7.2 library that had a helper class that used that package and worked fine from a .NET Framework 4.7.2 unit test project. We recently converted the library to target .NET Standard 2.0, and now this class breaks when used with the following error:

> ERROR: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>      at NetStandardRegistryLib.RegistryUtil..ctor(String remoteMachineName)
>      at NetStandardRegistryLib.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\src\Microsoft.Win32.Registry-IssueRepro\FrameworkRegistry\RegistryEditor\Program.cs:line 21

When I look at output of the Console project, I don't see the `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll` in the output.

Using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy#ilspy-------) and loading my .exe - it seems it would try to resolve the .dll from my dotnet core installation, which wouldn't work since it's a .NET Framework app.

## To Reproduce

I've created a repo that reproduces for me on my Windows 2010 machine. You can find it here: https://github.com/TylerNielsen/Microsoft.Win32.Registry-IssueRepro

Clone the repo, then open and build the `RegistryEditor` project.

Using Powershell or your favorite editor - call the tool with three required arguments [remoteMachineName] [Environment variable name to set] [Value to set on the environment variable] **

** Note, this actually requires a remote machine you can reference by IP address. For some reason using 127.0.0.1 doesn't work for me, but I'm unsure why. The use case for this utility is for accessing remote machine environment variables.

## Other Notes

When I create a .NET Framework Class Library to use for unit tests and reference the same .NET Standard Library - the `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` package is included and the utility runs just fine.

Comment: Your .NET Standard class library project must use multitargeting (`netstandard2.0` and `net45` for example) to work without such problems, https://blog.lextudio.com/tips-for-net-nuget-package-authors-august-2017-48f07604e4a0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your repo, if you look into both csproj files you'll see they are quite different. The NetStandardRegistryLib.csproj is the new format, the RegistryEditor.csproj is the old one.

Your problem is that old style projects do not resolve dependencies transitively. RegistryEditor will not copy dependencies of its own dependency NetStandardRegistryLib.

There are at least two ways to solve your problem:

1. Just add Microsoft.Win32.Registry Nuget package to RegistryEditor project explicitly. That'll make the Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll to appear in the RegistryEditor build folder.
2. Convert the RegistryEditor.csproj to new format. It's not limited to netstandard builds, you can use it for builds targeting .Net Framework versions as well. And it *does* resolve dependencies transitively!

Here's a long guide for how to do the conversion in general https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/

Since your project is quite simple, I've converted it for you. Just replace the content of RegistryEditor.csproj with the code below. It's still targeting `net472`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>RegistryEditor</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>RegistryEditor</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NetStandardRegistryLib\NetStandardRegistryLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that several properties that used to be in AssemblyInfo.cs file are provided by csproj file properties now, so you need to remove them from AssemblyInfo.cs to fix compilation errors:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("RegistryEditor")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("RegistryEditor")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Very interesting, I was under the impression that the new .csproj style only applied for when your project was going to be using .NET Core or .NET Standard. Didn't realize the new format was compatible with .NET Framework. The repo was just an example to show what I was running into. I'll do this with my real project - thanks!

On another note, is there a way to get Visual Studio to default to using the new project format even for .NET Framework projects?

Comment: I applied your .csproj file and saw that it now works with one small change - I needed to add  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> so that it actually generated the .exe as it's a console application.

Comment: Sorry that I missed the `OutputType`. Fortunately, after switching to the new format VS would allow you to adjust properties through its UI. I didn't find a way to make it default to the new format though. Just remember to switch right away before the project gets too complicated.